# how can i get value from tfoot datatable jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

plz i want to get the value of first tr in tfoot but i can't , here how i set the values :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">  
     $(document).ready(function() {
      //   Init DataTables 
        var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
           "fnFooterCallback": function( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {
               var solde = 20.35;
               nRow.getElementsByTagName('th')[4].innerHTML = solde.toFixed(2)+" $";
            }
       });
     });
</script>
```

how to get the value ??
thanks in advance.

Comment: If exactly `tr` value (html code), than `$('#datatable tfoot tr:first').html();`

Comment: thanks , but i can't see where do i specify the column ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using eq() function

```
$('tfoot').find('tr').eq(0).html()
```

Comment: $('tfoot').find('tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(0).html()
or
$('tfoot tr:first td:first').html()